# Declare variable with condition

Tags: javascript, php, variables, ternary

```
var foo, bar;

foo = 'hello'; // first
bar = 'world'; // otherwise

var baz = foo || bar;

console.log(baz);
```

wondering whats the PHP way of doing the above? I already know about the `ternary` operator:

```
$foo = $bar = '';

$foo = 'hello'; // first
$bar = 'world'; // otherwise

$baz = $foo ? $foo : $bar;

echo $baz;
```

.. but I'm looking to optimize here because the `$foo` in my case is MySQL query and I believe its executed twice(?) on check and then on assignment. Either way, I want to know if there's a more elegant DRY method of doing it.

**Edit:**

In PHP7 you can do:

```
$baz = $foo ?? $bar;
```

... but looking for something in PHP 5+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case, PHP provides a `?:` shorthand, which only evaluates the condition once:

```
$baz = $foo ?: $bar;
```

But apart from that it's functionally equivalent to `$foo ? $foo : $bar`.

EDIT: `$foo ?? $bar` is only for when `$foo` may be `null`. That operator is only available since PHP 7. `?:` however is available since PHP 5.3. The ternary will check for `false` (loosely).

Comment: Super! Thanks. Is it equivalent to the PHP7 `??` ?

Comment: @3zzy see my edit. `$foo = false; $baz = $foo ?? "alt"; $qux = $foo ?: "alt";` are different. But for truthy values, it's the same.

Comment: Ah ha, good to know. Thanks! Although I'm on PHP7 but I wanted the code to be backwards compatible.

Comment: `?:` works fine for `null`. The advantage of `??` is that it doesn't throw an error if the expression on its left is undefined. (Accessing a key that might not exist on an array and providing a default is an example of this use)

Comment: @TehJoE Note the tiny word _loosely_. I.e. everything falsy, like false, null, 0, "0", [], "", ...

Comment: I agree with you on how `?:` and the longer-form ternary work. I'm just pointing out the distinction vs `??`, in that `['a'=>1]['b'] ?? 2` won't throw an error but using `?:` will.